# Oracle: Ensure each value that used by the IN operator to always return one row even there is no match data

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my SQL query to find if a number of IDs have made a specific order. It joints 2 tables - `REQUEST` and `CODE` together in order to return the item name that sits in `CODE`:

```
SELECT GETCLIENT(a.CLI_ID,a.CLI_ID_SCH) AS Client, a.FILLER_FCTY AS Facility, a.FILLER_ORD AS OrderNumber, a.ORD_DATE AS DateTime, b.OBSC_DESC AS ItemName 
FROM REQUEST a, CODE b
WHERE a.SERV_ID = b.OBSID
AND GETCLIENT(a.CLI_ID,a.CLI_ID_SCH) IN
('AZZ1',
'BCA2',
'BDG3',
'BMZ4',
'BSH5',
'CAS6',
'CBW7')
AND FILLER_FCTY = 'TGY'
AND SERV_ID = '00034'
AND OBSC_DESC = 'Item A'
ORDER BY 1
```

The above query will returns the first 6 IDs(AZZ1, BCA2, BDG3, BMZ4, BSH5 and CAS6) with the expected result as they have made a relevant order, however, since the last ID **CBW7** have never made any order that is relevant to the specified Item number and Item name, no result is returned for this ID.

How can I make this ID or any ID to return a row even if there is no match on the database? I have tried to use `OR GETCLIENT(a.CLI_ID,a.CLI_ID_SCH) IS NULL` but still did not return a row for the last ID.

Comment: Hi, if you need to match rows from two tables, even if the condition is not meet, you need to use left join, instead of inner join.

Comment: `GETCLIENT(a.CLI_ID,a.CLI_ID_SCH) IN ...` ?

Comment: @Phantom . . . Your query is not syntactically correct.  Is it missing an `IN`?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Yes I have missed an operator when changing the value and have added it back. I have followed your concept and managed to get the value returns. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

In your case, you want a `LEFT JOIN`.  This is a bit complicated, partly because it is unclear where the columns are coming from.  You should qualify *all* column references.  And, use meaningful table aliases rather than arbitrary letters.

So, I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT l.Client,
       r.FILLER_FCTY AS Facility, r.FILLER_ORD AS OrderNumber, r.ORD_DATE AS DateTime,
       c.OBSC_DESC AS ItemName 
FROM (SELECT 'AZZ1' as client FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'BCA2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'BDG3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'BMZ4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'BSH5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CAS6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CBW7' FROM DUAL
     ) l LEFT JOIN
     (REQUEST r JOIN
      CODE c
      ON r.SERV_ID = c.OBSID AND
         ?.FILLER_FCTY = 'TGY' AND
         ?.SERV_ID = '00034' AND
         ?.OBSC_DESC = 'Item A'
     )
     ON GETCLIENT(r.CLI_ID, r.CLI_ID_SCH) = L.CODE      
ORDER BY 1;
```

The `?` are for the table aliases to identify where the columns come from.

Answer (score 0):

Create temp table of following values ('AZZ1',
'BCA2',
'BDG3',
'BMZ4',
'BSH5',
'CAS6',
'CBW7')
then Use left join with this temp table.